# Action bar item is not coming in Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to add a single item in my action bar. But even though I am using `showAction="always"` Still I am not able to see the icon in my action bar. Instead it is getting displayed once I click on Menu button.
Can someone point out what I am missing. I am following this tutorial : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: You have to add `appcompatv7` in your project if you used `yourapp:showAsAction=""`

Answer (score 0):

The menu will be shown on action bar depends on your mobile. When you use mobile without menu option or alter simply add `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` to your manifest element.

Answer (score 0):

I think your class is extending `ActionBarActivity` instead extend your class to `Activity`. This is because for backward compatibility for older version of Android.

**Edit**

Check whether you have a class like below:

```
@override
class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Then change it to like this and try:

```
@override
class MainActivity extends Activity {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Hope this is the issue. If it didn't work let me know!

Comment: I didnt get your explanation properly, can you elaborate? fyi I am using kitkat device.

Comment: You have a java class right? What it extends? Is it ActionBarActivity?

Comment: ...thanks for your input... but the solution suggested by MD worked for me.

Comment: Thats awesome! Keep going :)